# Convert JSON to Array of Objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, lodash

I have a JSON object in NoSql database in this format. We are getting this data after migrating some records from some other database and these are multi-valued fields.(Basically we are trying to clean the data for further processing).

```
{
    "BPContName":"aName;bName;cName",
    "BPContEmail":"aEmail;bEmail;cEmail",
    "BPContPWID":"aPWID;bPWID;cPWID"
}
```

I want to add another key "bpTableDataName" in the same JSON which should have this format and values,

```
"bpTableDataName": [
    {
      "name": "aName",
      "email": "aEmail",
      "pwdid": "aPWID"
    },
    {
      "name": "bName",
      "email": "bEmail",
      "pwdid": "bPWID"
    },
    {
      "name": "cName",
      "email": "cEmail",
      "pwdid": "cPWID"
    }
  ],
```

Is there a way we can achieve this using lodash?

Comment: you can do it in native javascript too

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Note: The fact it starts out as JSON is irrelevant. By the time you've parsed it, it's just an object, not a "JSON object."

Comment: @JaromandaX I am new to JavaScript actually. Can you please tell me how?

Comment: You have `PWID` in the original object but `pwdid` with an extra `d` in the output. Is that a spelling error?

Comment: @KirtiJha I have updated my answer to suit your use case.

Comment: @adiga Its not a spelling error. Its a Key as per the defined model. I can check if we can use "pwid" in place of "pwdid".

Comment: or `BPContPWDID` @KirtiJha?

Comment: @KirtiJha You can use custom keys, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()` to split the values into an array.
Then iterate over the array and create the require json and then push that into results.

Check this out.

```js
var data = {
    "BPContName":"aName;bName;cName",
    "BPContEmail":"aEmail;bEmail;cEmail",
    "BPContPWID":"aPWID;bPWID;cPWID"
}
var names = data.BPContName.split(';');
var emails = data.BPContEmail.split(';');
var pwids = data.BPContPWID.split(';');

var results = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < names.length; i++) {
  var obj = {
    name: names[i],
    email: emails[i],
    pwdid: pwids[i]
  }
  results.push(obj);
}

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code -

```js
o = {
  "BPContName": "aName;bName;cName",
  "BPContEmail": "aEmail;bEmail;cEmail",
  "BPContPWID": "aPWID;bPWID;cPWID"
}

map = { "BPContName" : "name", "BPContEmail": "email", "BPContPWID": "pwdid" }

const result = _.reduce(o, (arr, v, k) => ( v.split(";").forEach((x,i) => _.set(arr, `${i}.${map[k]}`, x)), arr ), [])
   
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: _ is not defined` ... fail

Comment: You must import lodash first : const _ = require('lodash')

Comment: `ReferenceError : require is not defined` ... still fail - don't make a runnable snippet that doesn't run - it doesn't look good

Comment: oh that's no good at all, you're basing the key on the data!! I think `aName;bName` etc are example place holders for such names as Adam, Brian, Charlie etc

Answer (score 0):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the entries returned by [`Object.entries`](http://Object.entries) like this:

```js
let obj = {
  "BPContName": "aName;bName;cName",
  "BPContEmail": "aEmail;bEmail;cEmail",
  "BPContPWID": "aPWID;bPWID;cPWID"
}

let bpTableDataName = Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
  let splits = value.split(";");
  key = key.replace("BPCont", "").toLowerCase();
  splits.forEach((split, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || {})[key] = split)
  return r;
}, [])

obj.bpTableDataName = bpTableDataName;

console.log(obj)
```

- `Object.entries` returns an array of key-value pair. Loop through each of them
- `split` the each value at `;`
- get the key by removing `BPCont` part and making it `lowerCase`
- Loop through the `splits` and update specific keys of objects at each index

Update:

Since you have an extra `d` in the output's key, you can create a mapping object:

```
propertyMap = {
  "BPContName": "name",
  "BPContEmail": "email",
  "BPContPWID": "pwdid"
}
```

And inside the `reduce`, change the `replace` code to this:

```
key = propertyMap[key]
```

Comment: I was going along your lines too, until I saw that :p

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.assign`, `Object.entries`, `Array#map` and the spread operator make this trivial

```js
    const inputdata = {
        "BPContName":"aName;bName;cName",
        "BPContEmail":"aEmail;bEmail;cEmail",
        "BPContPWID":"aPWID;bPWID;cPWID"
    };

    const t1=Object.assign({},...Object.entries(inputdata).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v.split(';')})));
    inputdata.bpTableDataName=t1.BPContName.map((name,i)=>({name,email:t1.BPContEmail[i],pwdid:t1.BPContPWID[i]}));
    console.log(inputdata);
```

Of course, it wouldn't be me without a one-liner

```js
const obj = {
    "BPContName":"aName;bName;cName",
    "BPContEmail":"aEmail;bEmail;cEmail",
    "BPContPWID":"aPWID;bPWID;cPWID"
};
// one line to rule them all
obj.bpTableDataName=Object.entries(obj).reduce((r,[k,v])=>(v.split(';').forEach((v,i)=>(r[i]=r[i]||{})[{BPContName:'name',BPContEmail:'email',BPContPWID:'pwdid'}[k]]=v),r),[]);
//
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's `_.flow()` to create a function. Use `_.map()` with `_.overArgs()` to create a function that splits the values, format the key, and then converts them to an array of pairs using `_.unzip()`, for example `[['name', 'x'], ['name', 'y']]`. Transpose the array of arrays with `_.unzip()` to combine pairs of different properties. Then use `_.map()` to iterate, and convert each array of pairs to an object using `_.fromPairs()`.

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, map, unzip, overArgs, times, size, constant, split, fromPairs } = _

const keysMap = new Map([['BPContName', 'name'], ['BPContEmail', 'email'], ['BPContPWID', 'pwdid']])

const formatKey = key => keysMap.get(key)
const splitVals = pr(split, ';')

const fn = flow(
  pr(map, overArgs(
    (vals, k) => unzip([vals, times(size(vals), constant(k))]),
    [splitVals, formatKey])
  ),
  unzip, // transpose
  pr(map, fromPairs) // convert each pairs array to object
)

const data = {
    "BPContName":"aName;bName;cName",
    "BPContEmail":"aEmail;bEmail;cEmail",
    "BPContPWID":"aPWID;bPWID;cPWID"
}

const results = fn(data)

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is to `zip` it.

Snippet:

```js
let obj = {"BPContName":"aName;bName;cName","BPContEmail":"aEmail;bEmail;cEmail","BPContPWID":"aPWID;bPWID;cPWID"},
    res = _.zipWith(
      ..._.map(obj, v => v.split(';')),
      (name, email, pwid) => ({name, email, pwid})
    );
    
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note, the sequence of the parameters we have to put such a way, the original object give us values when using `Object.values` or giving us keys when using `Object.keys` usually it is alphabetical order. But, In case in any env the order is not guranted we can sort it with a sequence of keys as a metadata.

Or else you can explicitly pass the arguments like:

```
(obj.BPContName.split(';'), obj.BPContEmail.split(';'), obj.BPContPWID.split(';'))
```